# Ignore Tiniest GIF Image Holder Requests from Asp.net Mvc Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image

I'm using asp.net mvc application for presentation project. and I'm using an image lazy loading plugin for my website. ( Blazy.js )

I put a image holder for images. It's "tiny image gif" as base64 for image sources.
Details are here; 
**The Tiniest GIF Ever**
http://probablyprogramming.com/2009/03/15/the-tiniest-gif-ever

But when I see logs, There are lot of errors like;

http://www.domain.com/data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==

```
{
  "Depth": 0,
  "ClassName": "System.Web.HttpException",
  "Message": "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).",
  "Source": "System.Web",
  "StackTraceString": "   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()\r\n   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)",
  "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
  "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
  "ExceptionMethod": {
    "Name": "ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig",
    "AssemblyName": "System.Web",
    "AssemblyVersion": "4.0.0.0",
    "AssemblyCulture": "",
    "ClassName": "System.Web.HttpRequest",
    "Signature": "Void ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()",
    "MemberType": 8
  },
  "HResult": -2147467259,
  "HelpURL": null
}
```

So, my question is: How can I block/ignore these requests from mvc side?
A configuration on mvc routeconfig perhaps? Or is there a better way to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can change this behavior by adjusting the [requestValidationMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestvalidationmode(v=vs.110).aspx) property. In version 4.0 and up of the framework it was changed to validate all requests. In version 2.0 it only validated pages as the documentation states:

> The RequestValidationMode property specifies which ASP.NET approach to
>   validation will be used. This can be the algorithm that is used in
>   versions of ASP.NET earlier than version 4, or the version that is
>   used in .NET Framework 4. The property can be set to the following
>   values:
>
> - 4.5 (the default). In this mode, values are lazily loaded, that is, they are not read until they are requested.
> - 4.0 The HttpRequest object internally sets a flag that indicates that request validation should be triggered whenever any HTTP request
>     data is accessed. This guarantees that the request validation is
>     triggered before data such as cookies and URLs are accessed during the
>     request. The request validation settings of the element (if any) in
>     the configuration file or of the directive in an individual page are
>     ignored.
> - 2.0. Request validation is enabled only for pages, not for all HTTP requests. In addition, the request validation settings of the element
>     (if any) in the configuration file or of the directive in an
>     individual page are used to determine which page requests to validate.

To change it back to 2.0 version you would do the following in your web.config.

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

If there are still issues you may also want to adjust the [requestPathInvalidCharacters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestpathinvalidcharacters(v=vs.110).aspx) property as well.